# Dlopen error in loading pytorch geometric

Tags: python, macos, pytorch, dlopen, pytorch-geometric

I'm trying to import torch_geometric through the following line of code:

```
from torch_geometric.data import Data
```

and keep running into the following error:

```
    dlopen(/Users/akumbhari/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/_convert_cpu.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN2at8internal13_parallel_runExxxRKNSt3__18functionIFvxxmEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/akumbhari/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/_convert_cpu.so
  Expected in: /Users/akumbhari/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib
 in /Users/akumbhari/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/_convert_cpu.so
```

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: `/Users/`? That looks like OSX, but you're explicitly asking about Linux-specific APIs according to the tags you applied. Also, please provide a [mcve]. It could also be that you messed up your system or that it's a simple bug (check according bugtrackers!). Concerning the error message, search for that online to get an idea what it means.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the lib files of your present environment.

- I suggest activating into your environment.
- Then pip uninstalling your torch_geometric lib
- Then finally reinstalling it.

If the error persists, then the best thing to do is to create a new empty environment and reinstall your packages.

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue for me was installing `torch-geometric` and its dependencies from wheels (instead of using e.g. conda).

See [installation via pip wheels](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html#installation-via-pip-wheels) in their documentation.